# How to create a hidden folder into an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, hide

How do I prevent images and folders on an Android app?

I have an app where I keep the images in your folders, but I do not want the images to be seen in the gallery,

How can I do that ?

Comment: try to used "." before created folder name, it will work

Comment: like @dex say... but, please! Google it first! It's one of the most common issues/fixes in Android since... forever.

Comment: create `.nomedia` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file inside that folder named "`.nomedia`"

Comment: But when I take the picture, the app keep picture in another folder called "Camera"

Answer (score 1):

All folders / files which start with . are hidden.
For instance .media